# Replace all occurrences of 'pattern' in part of a string using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace all '<' symbols that are in between apple and orange with '-'.

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(apple.*)<(.*orange)', r'\1-\2', r'apple < < orange')
```

> apple < - orange

```
>>> print re.sub(r'(apple.*)<(?=.*orange)', r'\g<1>-', r'apple < < orange')
```

> apple < - orange

Answer (score 0):

One invocation to `re.sub` only processes non-overlapping matches.

One way around that is brute force:

```
>>> s = 'apple < < orange'
>>> old = None
>>> while s != old:
...    old = s
...    s = re.sub(r'(apple.*)<(.*orange)', r'\1-\2', s)
... 
>>> print s
apple - - orange
```